# IllegalAccessException: Try to access hidden class using reflection

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an instance of StatusBarManager from:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/android/app/StatusBarManager.java#StatusBarManager

Here is the code I'm using to do so:

```
    try {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
        Object object = c.getDeclaredConstructor(Context.class).newInstance(context);

        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("expandNotificationsPanel",(Class<?>[]) null);
        try {
            m.invoke(object, (Object[]) null);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Howeverm I'm getting IllegalAccessException when trying to create the constructor. Any guidance on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

My first inclination is to say "don't do that".  Specifically, don't try to access or use private private classes, methods, constructors, or fields of the platform API, nor those of any third-party API either, for that matter.  The classes and members you're *intended* to use are `public`, or at most `protected`.

Supposing that you're going to insist on going ahead anyway, if you want to invoke a constructor that you do not have access to normally then, as you discovered, reflection does not automatically grant you access.  But you *can* reflectively obtain access.  To instantiate the class reflectively via that private constructor, you'll need first to invoke `setAccessible(true)` on the `Constructor` object before invoking `newInstance()`.

Comment: The class [is public](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0e2d281/core/java/android/app/StatusBarManager.java). Its his constructor which is package private

Comment: Thank you, @MatPag, I have revised the answer to address to situation more accurately.  Of course the bottom line -- use `setAccessible(true)` -- remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setAccessible(true)`

For me this code is compiling correctly:

```
try {
    //get the Class for the StatusBarManager
    Class className = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
    Constructor constructor = className.getDeclaredConstructor(Context.class);
    Method m = className.getDeclaredMethod("expandNotificationsPanel",(Class<?>[]) null);
    //set the constructor accessible and build an instance of it
    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    Object statusBarManager = constructor.newInstance(context);
    //invoke the method
    m.invoke(statusBarManager, (Object[]) null);
} catch (InstantiationException | 
         InvocationTargetException |
         NoSuchMethodException |
         IllegalAccessException |
         ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> **DISCLAIMER**: If you do this you must know that your code can break in
>   any moment with different Android versions or in Android(s) with custom
>   implementations by OEM.

Comment: @TerrelLewis please accept John's answer, He deserves it.

Answer (score 0):

`StatusBarManager` can only be constructed by other classes in its package (e.g. it is **package-private**). This means that you need to access it by other methods.